# Having trouble calling an array from one method to another in Java

Tags: java, arrays

The way I have my code set up is I declare my array in one method then I want to print it out in a table like fashion in another. But I want to do this while only using the main() function.

I have taken most of the irrelevant code out so here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] array) {
    test2(array);
}

public static void test() {
    String[] array = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"};
}

public static void test2( String[] array ) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) { 
            System.out.print(array[count] + "\t"); 
            count++;
        }   
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

When I try and run it, it comes up with the java.lang.ArrayOutOfBound on the line "System.out.print(array[count] + "\t");"

Does anyone know why this is and/or how to fix it?

Comment: The variable `array` in `test` is *local*. Local variables are not accessible outside of the block where they are declared. The variable `array` in `main` is passed directly to `test2`, but that's just your command-line arguments, and it has nothing to do with the `array` from `test`. And you are not calling `test()` anywhere anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several errors:

1. You create `array` as a local variable in `test()`.
2. You use the arguments of the application as parameters.
3. You don't even call `test()`.

The consequences are that you call your application probably with no parameters and end up having the `test2()` method trying to access the first element of an empty array, causing your exception.

This is what you should do, but keep reading after the code, I'm not done:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { // This array is defined, but don't use it.
  test2(test());
}

public static String[] test() {
  return new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"};
}

public static void test2( String[] array ) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) { 
      System.out.print(array[count] + "\t"); 
      count++;
    }   
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

This code has still issues. You indeed assume that you have 16 elements in your array. Yet you're not sure. Oh yes, you're sure because you've added them, but you shouldn't assume that it'll always be the case.

Therefore it's nice to check for the actual number of the elements anyways.

```
public static void test2( String[] array ) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      if (count < array.length) {
        System.out.print(array[count] + "\t"); 
        count++;
      }
    }   
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you for helping me as well as explaining my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't work because when your "main" calls "test2(array)" it passes nothing, since main doesn't have an "array" defined in it.

The array that you want exists only inside the "test" method.

So, one simple solution would be to change your code to:

```
public static void main(String[] array) {
    test2(test());
}

public static String[] test() {
    String[] array = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"};
    return array;
}

public static void test2( String[] array ) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) { 
            System.out.print(array[count] + "\t"); 
            count++;
        }   
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

...so that the method test() returns the array when it's called in main.

But, still, the code doesn't make lots of sense, especially in Object Oriented programming.

Comment: That code is exactly what I wrote in my answer, to the letter... 5 whole minutes before you. And my answer shows all the issues in the code, not the only obvious one.

Comment: I'm sorry that you feel like I copied you, but I was probably writing the answer at the same time as you.